# Bluetooth keeps turning on after suspend

Tags: suspend, bluetooth

I have tried to turn off Bluetooth, but every time I close and re-open the lid of my laptop, the Bluetooth service is up and running again.  Having Bluetooth on seems to interfere with my wifi connection when I am far away from the router(OT, but is this normal?).

I have read up on rfkill and even when I run `rfkill block bluetooth`, the same thing happens after I close and re-open the lid.

Any ideas how to stop this behaviour?  To be clear, I do want to be able to use Bluetooth occasionally, but I want it turned off by default.

The machine is an Asus nv56m and the ubuntu version is 19.04

system info for my laptop
[image: system info for my laptop]

screenshot of rfkill command being run
[image: screenshot of rfkill command being run]

Comment: Have you found a solution perhaps? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To disable Bluetooth on resume after suspend

1. Create a script disabling Bluetooth in file `/path/to/file/disable-bluetooth.sh`

   ```bash
   #!/usr/bin/env bash

   rfkill block bluetooth
   ```
2. Make it executable

   ```bash
   $ chmod +x /path/to/file/disable-bluetooth.sh
   ```
3. Create a file `/etc/systemd/system/disable-bluetooth.service`

   ```bash
   [Unit]
   Description=Disables Bluetooth
   Before=sleep.target
   StopWhenUnneeded=yes

   [Service]
   Type=oneshot
   RemainAfterExit=yes
   ExecStop=/path/to/file/disable-bluetooth.sh

   [Install]
   WantedBy=sleep.target
   ```
4. Enable the service

   ```bash
   $ sudo systemctl enable disable-bluetooth.service
   ```

### To disable Bluetooth on startup

Create a file `~/.config/autostart/disable-bluetooth.desktop`

```bash
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/path/to/file/disable-bluetooth.sh
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=Disable Bluetooth on startup
Name=Disable Bluetooth on startup
Comment[en_US]=
Comment=
```